# Bypass openvpn for particular ip

Tags: linux, vpn, routing, openvpn, gnu

My desktop machine runs Trisquel GNU/Linux 6.0 (which is basically a libre version of Ubuntu 12.04), and I use OpenVPN to connect to a commercial VPN provider for internet access.

It currently routes all my traffic through the VPN, which is great, but I'm looking for a way to allow requests to one specific IP address to bypass the VPN. I'm sure there's a way but repeated web searching hasn't yet turned up anything (best I could find were instructions for doing this on the Cisco VPN client for Windows).

Can you help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ip route add to $network/$mask via $gateway`

Comment: it think it is `ip route add network/mask via gatway`

Comment: Can you provide more specific example with this?

Answer (score 23):

Simply add a route for that IP to your local gateway.

You can do this in your openvpn client config like this.

```
route 10.99.77.55 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

In the config net_gateway is automatically replaced with the correct address.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I configured this vpn connection via NetworkManager, so there's no openvpn config file. Jeff's solution below worked for me.

Comment: Thats fine.  Do understand, that you will need to re-run that command every time the VPN has been established.  Routes do not persist across a reboot.  Heck they won't even persist across a disconnect of OpenVPN unless you pass the `persist-tun` option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You prompted me to look further into this, and I discovered that I could make this permanent by adding the information to the "routes" dialog on the IPv4 tab of the NetworkManager settings for my eth0 connection.

Comment: This worked like a charm for config files from CitizenVPN

Comment: Remember that you may need to reimport your profile in order for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

```
route 10.99.77.55 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

I used this code line in ovpn config so it worked.
Now I want to bypass an IP range instead of single IP, How can I do it?

something like that:

```
route 10.99.77.55/22 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/509614)