# IP address visibility when connecting through a VPN

Tags: openvpn

`Client` is connecting to `Host A` using OpenVPN.

- `Client` can now reach `Host B` (Routes created on `Client` machine by OpenVPN client)
- `Host B` can now reach `Client` (Routes manually created on `Host B`)

When `Client` does an HTTP request to `Host B`, `Host B` sees `Host A`s IP address. This is normal and how the VPN should work.

How can I port forward from `Host A` to `Client`, so that `Host B` does not need to know `Host A`s address?

Comment: *"What is the best solution so that Host B sees Client's IP address instead?"* - That should only happen when traffic from the Client to HostB is NOT routed over the VPN connection, along the lines of [this Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/487468/37681). Is that what you want?

Comment: I actually want to route traffic from `Host B` to `Client`. During `Request/Response` context this works, as NAT table will figure routing out. Would this connection be possible, using `Host A`s ip, but AFTER NAT table is cleared? Maybe some sort of `OpenVPN server` to `client` port forwarding? I will rephrase question

Answer (score 0):

Without using OpenVPN myself, I would say the VPN machine is using NAT and though hiding the client IP addresses.

[This link](https://superuser.com/questions/974327/disable-nat-in-openvpn) may explane how to do it.